# Disable Submit button on selection from DropDownListFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html.dropdownlistfor

I am working on this code when the submit button will be enabled only when user selects values from a DropDownListFor.

```
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Year, Model.YearList, "--Select Year--", new { @class = "form-control",id = "Year" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Year)

 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
```

js code:

```
   $("#Year").change(function () {
        if ($('#Year').val()!="--Select Year--")
            $('.submit').prop("disabled", false);
        else
            $('.submit').prop("disabled", true);
    });
```

No error message just the submit button is always enabled. Any help?

Comment: try $('#Year').val() != '' ; or if default value is 'defval'; try $('#Year').val() != 'defval'

Comment: @RajkumarSomasundaram even this doesn't work.

Comment: your `.submit` is a class selector but your submit button is only defined by `id` and `name`. The class `submit` is not mentioned in your code that you shared

Comment: tried with #submit. Still not working

Comment: Downvoter , may i know what is wrong with the question?

Comment: Did you actually check if the rendered component really has the ID `Year` did you step through if you actually hit the change eventhandler? No error message doesn't necessarily mean that nothing went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this, it will work you can also use

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlYear", new SelectList(mylist, "Value", "Text"), "-- Select Year--", new { @class = "form-control input-sm", onchange = "Button()" })
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlYear", ((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["mylist"]), "-- Select Year--", new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "Button()" })
```

Or using DropDownListFor

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
        })
        function Button()
        {
            if ($('#ddlYear').val() != "") {
                document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
            }
        }
    </script>

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Year, Model.YearList, "--Select Year--", new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddlYear", onchange = "Button()" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Year)
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" onchange="Button()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code cause selector use class but no submit class so you id selector in your javascript code

```js
$("#Year").change(function () {
    if ($('#Year').val()) {
    $('.submit').prop("disabled", false);
}
else {
    $('.submit').prop("disabled", true);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Year">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>

<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success submit" />
```

Comment: @shreyPav check this code, first time disabled button for checking then if value then remove

Comment: yeah this code works with select tag. But in my question I am using DropDownListFor. For which it isn't working

Comment: @shreyPav this is your exact code without DropDownListFor so all working

Comment: Yeah.. still wondering why its not working with DropDownListFor

Comment: @shreyPav did you add class submit in your submit button?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with @Html.DropDownListFor;

But given your questions's demand (which was mainly on js part); I used direct html tags;

nonetheless this solution should work for you;

Hope this helps;

```js
let allOptions = document.querySelectorAll("#year option");
let allChoices = [];
for(i=0;i<allOptions.length;i++) {
 allChoices.push(allOptions[i].innerHTML);
}

$("#inputBox").on('keyup',function () {
 
        if (allChoices.indexOf(document.getElementById("inputBox").value) != -1)
            $('.submit').attr("disabled", true);         
        else        
            $('.submit').attr("disabled", false);        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="year">
 <option>defaultvalue</option>
 <option>option1</option>
 <option>option2</option>
 </select>

<input type="text" id="inputBox"/>
 <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" >submit
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript you set the button as disabled and use an onchange function to check for value:

```
<select id="Year" onchange = "enableButton()">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" disabled/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function enableButton(){
 var year =  document.getElementById("Year").value;
 if(year == ""){
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
 }
 else{
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
 }
}
```